# Size of a Graphviz Graph

Tags: graphviz

I'm creating a circular graph that contains a thousand edges. 
It works fine if I only put a few in there, e.g., I can vary the edge length. However, when I put all the data in, I can't seem to control the size anymore. The picture just blows up ridiculously large with just tiny nodes and huge (HUGE) distance to the other nodes.

I'm trying to influence the length and size using weight, size, len, etc. but nothing seems to work. Anyone any ideas how to control the size of the graph?

Answer (score 10):

Use size="width,heigth!" (the exclamation mark is important here)

width and height are "Maximum width and height of drawing, in inches."

Comment: Why is the ! important?

Comment: From http://graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html#d:size — "If size ends in an exclamation point (!), then it is taken to be the desired size. In this case, if both dimensions of the drawing are less than size, the drawing is scaled up uniformly until at least one dimension equals its dimension in size."